# Flask SQLAlchemy db session commit pattern

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

If we have a large set of data that we want to add to our database;

```
for k, v in df.iterrows():
    sales = Sales( date=v[0], client_name=v[1], client_code=v[2])
    db.session.add(sales)
    db.session.commit() #1)HERE
db.session.commit() #2)HERE
```

I was wondering the frequency that we should commit(). For example should we commit really frequently  #1) HERE or after everything is added #2) HERE. Most of the examples refers to #2 but with a really large set of data would this be possible - no bust in memory?

Comment: you should do #2.
I don't think it causes a problem

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
for k, v in df.iterrows():
    sales = Sales( date=v[0], client_name=v[1], client_code=v[2])
    db.session.add(sales)
db.session.commit()
```

You must commit everything which has been there in your session at the end of your code.